# How to fix index match run-time error 9 and sheet and column variable not defined?

Tags: vba, indexing, runtime-error, match, undefined

I struggle solving the following error message: run time error 9 subscript out of range. The debugger refers to the following line:

```
LastRow = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Sometimes "Sheet1" and "A" are highlighted and an error message appears saying that "Sheet1" and "A" were not defined...

Here is the full code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
MsgBox “Pls select a value from the drop down list!”
Exit Sub
End If
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “A”).Value = Me.ComboBox1 Then
Me.TextBox1 = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “B”).Value
End If
Next
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


If Me.ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
For i = 2 To LastRow
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “A”).Value
Next i
End If
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Best, Joshua

Comment: Your code has "smart quotes" in place of regular quotes. Compare `“”` vs. `""` You need to fix those.  Possibly you copy-pasted the code from somewhere else?

Comment: To expand on that: VBA doesn't see smart quotes as actual quotes, just an another regular character, so your code is literally looking for `"“Sheet1”"` (where the smart quotes are an actual part of the sheet name.